# SELECT count(*) on Intermediary Table with Many-Many relationship Only if Exists in Both Related Tables

Tags: mysql, sql, select, many-to-many

I have 3 tables: `users`, `courses` and `courseusers`. Courseusers is the intermediary table that joins courses.idCourse with users.idUser. However, the intermediary table has no foreign key constrains and `ON DELETE CASCADE` or `ON UPDATE CASCADE`.

```
Users:
idUser|name

Courses:
idCourse|name

Courseusers:
id|idUser|idCourse
```

My question is, how do I get the top 3 most subscribed courses (most entries in `courseuser`), while ignoring manually deleted users from the `users` and `courses` tables (they will still exists as entries in `courseuser`).

What I have right now:

```
SELECT c.idCourse, c.name, count(*) as count 
FROM courseusers as cu 
     JOIN course as c 
         ON cu.idCourse=c.idCourse 
     JOIN users as usr 
         ON (usr.idUser=u.idUser) 
GROUP BY u.idCourse
ORDER BY count DESC 
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use the following query

```
SELECT c.idCourse, c.name, count(*) as count  
FROM courseusers as cu  
   LEFT JOIN course as c  
       ON cu.idCourse=c.idCourse  
   LEFT JOIN users as usr  
       ON (usr.idUser=u.idUser)  
GROUP BY u.idCourse 
ORDER BY count DESC  
LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 3):

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0567a/1

```
SELECT
  c.name,
  COUNT(1) AS total
FROM Courceusers cu
JOIN Cources c USING(idCource)
JOIN Users u USING(idUser)
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 2 DESC
LIMIT 3;
```

Answer (score 1):

Join all tables based on table `Users` not on the intermediary table

```
SELECT  a.idUser, a.Name, COUNT(c.idCourse) totalCount
FROM    Users a
            INNER JOIN  CourseUsers b
                ON a.idUser = b.idUser
            INNER JOIN Courses c
                ON b.idCourse = c.idCourse
GROUP BY a.idUser, a.Name
ORDER BY totalCount DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
    CourseUsers.idCourse, 
    Courses.name, 
    COUNT(distinct CourseUsers.idUser) as Subscribers
from CourseUsers
    inner join Courses on CourseUsers.idCourse = Courses.idCourse
    inner join Users on CourseUsers.idUser = Users.idUser
group by CourseUsers.idCourse, Courses.name
order by Subscribers desc
limit 3
```